# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable [GGplot2, Shiny]

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using shiny to create a simple app.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Power Breakdown!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel()
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plt"))
      )
     ) )
```

and server.R is (needed dataset is at [loc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aon4w42p1ibin4q/mydata.Rdata?dl=0))

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df <- readRDS("dataframe-path")
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
     output$plt <- renderPlot({
       df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp)
       p <- ggplot(df,aes(df$timestamp,df$power))+theme_bw() +geom_point()
       print(p)
       })
    })
```

When I run this application, following error is generated

```
Error in df$timestamp : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Whenever I run the same server script as a normal R script everything works properly, but while using same code snippet in shiny results in above error.

Note: I referred the same question at links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595637/r-shiny-reactive-subset-data-error-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240434/r-shiny-error-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790152/r-shiny-not-sure-why-ggplot-is-failing) , but without any success

Comment: Then try changing" `p <- ggplot(df,aes(df$timestamp,df$power))+theme_bw() +geom_point()` to `p <- ggplot(df,aes(timestamp,power))+theme_bw() +geom_point()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I don't know the reason why the same code works in a standalone R script, but fails in shiny. Really, crazy. Please put your comment as an answer.

Comment: It's related to the way `ggplot` [scopes itself inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287498/scoping-of-variables-in-aes-inside-a-function-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the `df$` from inside the `aes` call:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(timestamp,power))+theme_bw() +geom_point()
```

This is because of how `aes` [is scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287498/scoping-of-variables-in-aes-inside-a-function-in-ggplot)